# How to close php page from browser after executing the code?

Tags: php

I have a code in php which I want to schedule in task scheduler. But when this page runs it opens tab in my browser window. I want to close it anyway after execution or is there any way to run php page without opening tab in browser?
I have tried `window.close();` but it's also not working.

Comment: Did you put `window.close();` inside `<script>` tags? Not working means it gives you an error or it just doesn't close the browser window?

Comment: please show us the relevant code which illustrates your setup: did I get you right that you have automated opening a browser window by schedule? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL. to run code in background or without opening browser tab.

see documentation [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

`filename.php`

```
<?php 
echo "I am here";
//here some php code

//adding close browser tab code
?>
<script>
     window.close();
</script>
<?php
    //here some php code
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run the script from your command line. There is no need to involve a browser at all.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php